# Unable to verify ID for Google Developer account after new account creation

Tags: store, publish, playback

i recently created a new account on google play publish for publish my apps. Now google is asking me to verify the ID for company, but i am a individual person. I don't run a company and want to publish my apps on play store. I have submitted a copy of CNIC but google has not accepted it.

Comment: Should we know what is a "CNIC"?

Comment: Me too stucked with this issue. I am an individual and I don't own any company. Have you solved that issue ? Can you guide me please ?